# Redefining home in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I'm working on a Django project in which I plan to make user profiles. My goal is to have a standard login page as seen [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron). After logging in, however, I want to redefine

```
url(r'^$', 'MyApp.views.home', name='home'),
```

to not show this page, but a user profile with the same url as home.

For example, www.example.com shows a login screen. After logging it, you're redirected to www.example.com, but you see your profile now.

How can I do this in Django?

Comment: In your `view` you would check to see if the user is logged in or not and branch accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally how I would go about it. You can add context if needed.

`views.py:`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return user_home(request)
    else:
        return login_home(request)

def user_home(request)
    return render(request, 'path/to/user_template.html')

def login_home(request)
    return render(request, 'path/to/login_template.html')
```

Comment: did you test it? view must return HttpResponse, not another view function

Comment: Here I'm using the [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut django provides. It returns an HttpResponse object itself.

Comment: are you sure? i thought ``render`` renders RequestContext, but i meant HttpResponse and by that i meant of course your ``home`` function and not the last 2.

Comment: although this works; there are much more simple ways. you don't need to call a new function, just change what template is passed to the render().

Answer (score 1):

You need simple check in view:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/profileurl/')
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do it would be a redirect to another view:

`MyApp.views`

```
def home(request):
  if request.user.is_authenticated():
    redirect
  else:
    home page
```

If you want the actual url entry to load a different template than the home page, or a modified home page, you could just as easily render whatever template you wanted in response to the url request instead of issuing a redirect